# SE API: Recent OAuth 2.0 implicit flow breaking change

Tags: bug, status-review, api

### Changed behavior: Unexpected values returned with the `access_token` when using the *implicit* OAuth 2.0 flow

We are, now, seeing additional `scope` data included in the hash for the URL used as the redirect in the SE API implicit OAuth 2.0 flow. This did not previously happen.

With the [SE API implicit OAuth 2.0 flow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), the authorization token is supposed to be returned to the application as the URL hash (the part after the "#" in a URL) to the redirected URL.

For FIRE, which we use with SmokeDetector, that URL hash used to look like:

```
#access_token=<token>
```

As of now, the hash looks like:

```
#access_token=<token>&scope=write_access%20no_expiry
```

We can adapt to this change, but it's inconsistent with [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), which is clear that the `scope` should not be included in the hash and that an `expires` value should only be included if there's an expiration time for the token, which FIRE doesn't have, due to requesting `no_expiry`. While we can change FIRE to accommodate this difference, there are probably a significant number of applications which will be affected by this change. At a minimum, please change the documentation to clearly state what's going to happen during the implicit OAuth 2.0 flow. However, better, in my opinion, would be to return to the prior operation.

We don't have good information as to when this change happened.

No changes were made to FIRE or the way the SE API is used.

Comment: I've just experienced this issue trying to log in from MS using SE.

Comment: @Nick While I've mentioned the logging-in issue at the bottom of this question as potentially associated, it doesn't appear to be the same issue, as far as I've seen. The login issue on MS is *probably* that something is causing the IP that MS uses to become rate limited. At the moment, I don't know for sure that's the login issue, but MS being rate limited *way* more than normal is definitely causing other issues, such as the high number of failed autoflags (normally zero) seen in the graph at the bottom of [this page](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging).

Comment: Apart from what it's showing, that is a beautiful graph!

Comment: I've removed mention of the issues on MS, as their cause has been identified as a quota issue and resolved. There is a unresolved issue that the SE API quota system wasn't working exactly as previously stated it would work and as I'd previously tested it to work, but that's a separate issue, which should be a separate bug report.

Comment: The change happened in May of this year. I'll have to ask around internally to fully understand the motivation and the person who made it is on vacation, so it'll take some time. I suspect there's a non-zero chance we'll end up updating the documentation here to match the behavior, but I'll see what we can do. FWIW, `expires` isn't being included here. That `no_expiry` bit is technically part of the `scope`.